# How to use OR on Laravel Collection

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel collection, where each element has key `action` and value can be 'Manual', 'automatic' and other types. I m trying to get all elements where `action` is either 'manual' OR 'Automatic'
I have tried following the Laravel collection method but it returns nothing.

```php
$manualTransactions = $allTransactions
    ->where('action','Manual')
    ->where('action','Used');
```

However, if I try the following, it returns all elements where `action` is 'Manual' also if I replace 'Manual' with 'Used' it returns all elements where `action` is 'Used'

```php
$manualTransactions = $allTransactions
    ->where('action','Manual');
```

Question: How to get all elements where `action` is 'Manual' OR 'Used'? I saw Laravel collection Methods but I found nothing like orWhere method.

Comment: You could use [whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-wherein) instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could either use [whereIn()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-wherein):

```
$allTransactions->whereIn('action', ['Manual', 'Used']);
```

Or [filter()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-filter):

```
$allTransactions->filter(function ($item) {
    return in_array($item->action, ['Manual', 'Used']);
});
```

The above assumes `$item` is an object, use `$item['action']` if it is an array.